# How do I hide instance variables from the Ruby layer in my C-extension?

Tags: ruby, ruby-c-extension

I am looking into example from [Programming Ruby 1.9](http://media.pragprog.com/titles/ruby3/ext_ruby.pdf). Is it possible to create instance variables not exposed to Ruby, visible only in C - for example to initialize C-structure in t_init and use it in t_add ?

If I declare the structure or variable below the id_push, it is class structure/variable and I need instance.

Is it possible to achieve without using Data_Wrap_Struct/Data_Get_Struct or rb_iv_set/rb_iv_get, as the instance variable is not needed in Ruby, it is enough to be visible from C only?

```
#include "ruby.h"

static ID id_push;

// how to define instance variables here?

static VALUE t_init(VALUE self) {
    VALUE arr;
    arr = rb_ary_new(); 
    rb_iv_set(self, "@arr", arr); 
    return self;
}

static VALUE t_add(VALUE self, VALUE obj) {
    VALUE arr;
    arr = rb_iv_get(self, "@arr"); 
    rb_funcall(arr, id_push, 1, obj); 
    return arr;
}

VALUE cTest;

void Init_my_test() {
    cTest = rb_define_class("MyTest", rb_cObject); 
    rb_define_method(cTest, "initialize", t_init, 0); 
    rb_define_method(cTest, "add", t_add, 1); id_push = rb_intern("push");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C functions you are looking for are **`rb_ivar_set`** and **`rb_ivar_get`.**

`rb_ivar_set` takes three arguments:

1. the `VALUE`-type Ruby receiver object
2. the `ID`-type ivar name to assign
3. the `VALUE`-type Ruby right-hand-side object.

`rb_ivar_get` takes two arguments:

1. the `VALUE`-type Ruby receiver object
2. the `ID`-type ivar name to retrieve

Ruby can store instance variables internally with many kinds of `ID`-type name. The only variable names made visible from the Ruby layer, though, are the ones that begin with `@`, e.g. `rb_intern("@foo")`. **Leaving out the `@` makes the instance variable inaccessible from the Ruby layer, but allows you to store and access it from the C layer.**

---

Here is your code sample with this technique implemented.

```
#include "ruby.h"

static ID id_push;

static VALUE t_init(VALUE self) {
    VALUE arr;
    arr = rb_ary_new();
    rb_ivar_set(self, rb_intern("arr"), arr); /* <-- */
    return self;
}

static VALUE t_add(VALUE self, VALUE obj) {
    VALUE arr;
    arr = rb_ivar_get(self, rb_intern("arr")); /* <-- */
    rb_funcall(arr, id_push, 1, obj);
    return arr;
}

VALUE cTest;

void Init_my_test() {
    cTest = rb_define_class("MyTest", rb_cObject); 
    rb_define_method(cTest, "initialize", t_init, 0); 
    rb_define_method(cTest, "add", t_add, 1); id_push = rb_intern("push");
}
```

---

Test it out! It should run like this (I didn't compile the above, there may be typos):

```
require 'my_test'

class MyTest
  def check
    return @arr
  end
end

t = MyTest.new
t.add(1) #=> [1]
t.check #=> nil
```

The `#check` method goes looking for the `@arr` instance variable and comes up empty-handed. Your instance variables are safe and sound, locked up in the C layer!

Comment: That's horrendous :-) It might work though - are you certain that GC will do the right thing with these partly-accessible things? Does any well-respected extension library actually use this technique as a shortcut (to hide instance variables added by C)?

Comment: OK, found difference between `rb_iv_set` and `rb_ivar_set`, it makes sense now (and +1), initially I thought you were suggesting to use `rb_iv_set` without the `@` . . .

Comment: It works, I can now save/get C structures as class instance variables, visible in C only and no segfaults occur in irb when the shell tries to display them and conf.echo is active. The Ruby garbage collector will clean those variables as well, or?

Comment: Yup. The garbage collector cleans them up in the exact same way it cleans up your regular `@foo` instance variables.